# jquery validation form logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, logic

I have another logic question that I am getting stuck with. I need this form to only allow either one or the other. Either the text input or the checkbox, not both!

```
}else if(question_pos==7){
        if(!($('#test_check').prop('checked')) && $("#test").val()!="0" &&  ($("#test").val() =="" || 
                !Number($("#test").val()) ||  Number($("#test").val())<0 || Number($("#test").val())>20 )){
          alert("placeholder?");
          return false;
```

the inputs:

```
    <table class="screening" width="100%" cellspacing="5px">
    <tr>
        <td width="8%" align="right"><input name="test" id="test" type="text" pattern="\d*" size="3" maxlength="2"  value="<%=session.getAttribute("test")==null?"":session.getAttribute("test")%>"/>
     </td>
     <td>day(s)</td>
</tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="8%" align="right" valign="top"><input name="test_check" id="test_check" type="checkbox" value="1" <%=(session.getAttribute("test_check")!=null && session.getAttribute("test_check").equals("1"))?"checked":""%>/></td>
        <td width="92%"><label for="test_check">My baby is still in the hospital</label></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The validation needs to make sure that there is no text input if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: please post the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to check if the `checked` property is true and if the field contains some characters. If both conditions are met, it means the form's state is invalid.

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/g4q34/

*You should avoid calling `$("#test")` over and over, it makes the code less readable and is very inefficient performance-wise. Store a reference in a variable and reuse that variable instead.*

```
var checked = $('#test_check').prop('checked'),
    val = $("#test").val();

if (checked && val.length) {
    //invalid
} else {
    //the checkbox is checked OR the input contains text, but not BOTH
}
```

Here's an example with your own code:

```
} else if (question_pos==7) {
        if($('#test_check').prop('checked') && $("#test").val().length) {
            alert("placeholder?");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: @user2089255, "Either the text input or the checkbox", this is exactly what the following code shows. It will enter the `if` statement only if the input contains text and the checkbox is checked. Is there something else I did not understand?

Comment: I think my verify is ok, but it appears that somewhere in there is a logic error or a misplaced parenthesis or wrong (not) comma.

Comment: @user2089255, the following answer's your question as it is. Please update your question if that's not what you want.

Comment: The validation needs to make sure that there is no text input if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: No sorry, I mean that if any text is in the text input box and the the checkbox is checked, I need an error message.

Comment: @user2089255, I don't want to be rude, but I don't get what you don't understand in my answer. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/g4q34/ ... is this what you want?

Comment: This works, but outside of the format that I need it in, Ill work with the jsfiddle and see how that goes, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working exactly how I needed it. I just had to drink some coffee and wake up!

```
}else if(question_pos==7){
    if(!$('#example_check').prop('checked') && $("#example").val()!="0" &&  ($("#example").val() =="" || !Number($("#example").val()) ||  Number($("#example").val())<0 || Number($("#example").val())>20 )){
    alert("How long did your baby stay in the hospital?");
    return false;
    }else if($('#example_check').prop('checked') && $("#example").val().length) {
    alert("Have you taken your baby home or is your baby still in the hospital?");
    return false;
```

I changed the "test" to "example"